# How to make hard break/return in an answer?

Tags: support

Is it possible to make a hard break/return in an answer? I've tried the normal keyboard shortcut of SHIFT+ENTER which shows the return correctly in the WYSIWYG textarea but not in the answer preview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure shift+enter is a "soft" return (a line break, as opposed to a paragraph break).

Semantics aside, since Stack Exchange uses Markdown formatting just put two spaces at the end of the line and then press return. Or you can just use a `<br>` tag in your answer.

Here
is a line break made with Markdown

Comment: Just tested both options. Worked! Thank you for the direction.